# How to set value inside nested forEach() in java8?

Tags: foreach, java-8, stream

I have a case in which I am iterating the `List<DiscountClass>` and need to compare the list value with another `List<TypeCode>`, based on satisfying the condition (when `Discount.code` equals `TypeCode.code`) I need to set `Discount.setCodeDescr()`. How to achieve this with nested forEach loop in java 8? (I am not able to set after comparing the values in java 8 forEach).

```
for (Discount dis : discountList) {
    for (TypeCode code : typeCodeList) {
        if (dis.getCode().equals(code.getCode())) {
            dis.setCodeDesc(code.getCodeDesc());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `po` and what is `b`?

Comment: sorry, edited now.

Comment: Your `TypeCode` should ideally be an enum, with a `desc` field. Even a `Map` would be better than a list of `TypeCode`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution using java 8 lambdas could look like this:

```
    discountList.forEach(dis -> {
        typeCodeList
          .stream()
          .filter(code -> dis.getCode().equals(code.getCode()))
          .findAny()
          .ifPresent(code -> dis.setCodeDesc(code.getCodeDesc()));
    });
```

For each  discount you filter the TypeCodes according to the code and if you find any you set the desc poperty to the one of the found TypeCode.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer showed how to convert a nested loop to a nested functional loop.
But instead of iterating over a list of `TypeCode`, it's better to use a `HashMap` to get random access, or an enum like this:

```
public enum TypeCode {
    CODE_1("description of code 1"),
    CODE_2("description of code 2");

    private String desc;

    TypeCode(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
}

public class Discount {

    private String typeCode; //assuming you can't have the type as TypeCode
    private String desc;

    public Discount(String typeCode) {
        this.typeCode = typeCode;
    }

    //getters/setters
}
```

Then your code will change to:

```
Discount d1 = new Discount("CODE_1");
Discount d2 = new Discount("CODE_2");

List<Discount> discounts = List.of(d1, d2);
discounts.forEach(discount ->
        discount.setDesc(TypeCode.valueOf(discount.getTypeCode()).getDesc()));
```

Comment: This works for Hashmap, in my case I m using list (of course I can keep as hashmap),but requirement is to keep as list. Thanks for your solution :)